# Jumping to a specified window in Emacs doesn't work when done programatically

Tags: emacs, window

I am trying to select the third window (I have opened 6 in my frame) in Emacs.

The problem is that this:

```
(select-window 3)
```

doesn't work.

It throws this error in debugger:

> (wrong-type-argument window-live-p 3)

How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select-window` takes a window object as argument, not a number. The function `window-list` gives you a list of window objects in the current frame. You can select one of them to pass to `select-window`, e.g.

```el
(select-window (nth 2 (window-list)))
```

will select the window that is the third[1] element of the list that `window-list` returns.

Do `C-h f nth` and `C-h f window-list` for more information on these functions.

**EDIT**: in response to the comment...

- What I know about Windows (which is not much), I've learned by reading parts of the [Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Windows.html) chapter in the Emacs Lisp Reference manual.
- Do *NOT* expect the window number to correspond to anything that you think as "first" or "second" or ...
  When you destroy windows and then create new ones, the numbers are going to change unpredictably (at least AFAIK), e.g. I had three windows with numbers 51, 83 and 99. I destroyed window #99 and created a new one: now `window-list` tells me I have windows with numbers 51, 105 and 83 *in that order*. I believe (but I may be wrong) that Emacs uses the list returned by `window-list` in order to implement `other-window` (`C-x o`), so the order of the list that `window-list` returns depends on what your selected window is currently: that' always the first element of the list, so the window you'll select with `C-x o` is the second element of the current list, but when you get there and do `ESC ESC : (window-list)`, the returned list will have changed - it will be rotated so that where you are is the first element and where you came from is now the *last* element. See [Cyclic Ordering of Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Cyclic-Window-Ordering.html) in the Emacs Lisp Reference manual.
- You are correct that the upper case WINDOW in the function description is a hint of its type. For typographic conventions, see the section [Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Conventions.html) in the Emacs Lisp Reference manual and in particular, the subsection [A Sample Function Description](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/A-Sample-Function-Description.html).

---

[1] Note that list elements are indexed from 0.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Although nth 0 doesn't worked. nth 1 is bound to window 1 nth 2 to window 2, perhaps nth 0 is bound to window 0, which I don't know I could've because after 9 it goes to 10, 11, etc. Also, where do you get this information? Source code? Because in the Emacs docs in help for select-window function there is nothing about objects. For example, they write WINDOW in uppercase for some reason, but I don't know anything about it type. It's not mention there. But perhapsy there is an explanation earlier in the manual (yes I didn't read it) that uppercased letters represent objects.

Comment: Edited the answer to add some clarifications/caveats/additional information. Dealing with windows programatically is not part of "Emacs 101": it's a more advanced course :-)

Comment: If needed, you could sort the result of `(window-list)`. It seems it's a freshly new list since `(eq (window-list) (window-list))` returns `nil`. To sort this list, you could use the result of `window-edges` or the "sequence_number" of each window (if you find how to get it).